# read data from xlsx file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use an xlsx file with some data in the columns, as a database but my data is not loading. I have tried to use a function to convert the file to JSON by parsing it from its path, add it to a variable and then load the data into a bootstrap table in the specific column. Could you help me please?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap table.min.css">

<script>
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(json_object);
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_object)
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };

  var data1 = new ExcelToJSON().parseExcel("bookinfo.xlsx");
//start

$(document).ready(function () {    
$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data1
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text text-success text-center ">
    list of something
    </h1>
    <table class="table-striped border-success">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">
            <span class="text-success">
             ID
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="name">
            <span class="text-success">
             Name
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="date">
            <span class="text-success">
             Date
            </span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
</body>
```